# How could Chris be hurt while bathing, when/because his wife flushes the toilet?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-sniper

Almost at the end of *American Sniper* (about 119 minutes), Chris Kyle's wife flushes the toilet when he is bathing, and Chris fakes getting hurt.

However, how *can* he get hurt by what his wife is doing? What can happen when she flushes the toilet while he's bathing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Flushing the toilet or turning on the cold water at a sink (in older houses) diverts cold water away from the shower in order to fill the toilet tank or fill the sink. He wasn't faking getting hurt, the water in his shower suddenly turned extra hot.

Comment: Did seen something like that on one YouTube prank, +1.